# My copy constructor is causing my methods which use my class to fail. Can someone take a look at it and tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Tags: c++, oop, class, destructor, copy-constructor

My constructor creates a copy just fine - but when a method takes an IntegerNumber as an argument, it stops working.

My constructor:

```
IntegerNumber::IntegerNumber(const IntegerNumber &integerInput){
//Creates a copy of an Integer Number
//Set len and isNegative
len = integerInput.len; 
isNegative = integerInput.isNegative;
//Fill integer with IntegerInput
integer = new char[len+1];
for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    integer[i]=integerInput.integer[i];
}
```

My destructor:

```
IntegerNumber::~IntegerNumber(){
//Destructs IntegerNumber
delete [] integer;
delete &len;
delete &isNegative;
}
```

My Class' data members:

```
private:
    char *integer;
    int len;
    bool isNegative;
```

Please try and help me figure out what could be wrong with my constructor/destructor such that the program stops but doesnt crash or break?

Comment: `delete &len` looks highly suspicious. Can you show your class definition?

Comment: Use `delete` where you use `new` (the same for the `[]` "versions")

Comment: @CharlesBailey - `len` is `int`

Comment: I'm curious, what does "stops working" mean, as it's does not crash or break :?

Comment: returns me to the console with no indication of anything having gone wrong, when i stepped through the program it would just "stop" after I tried calling a method that had my object in one of its arguments. It would perform the method and return a value, but once we went back to the method which called it it would just stop and return to the console.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Exactly one `delete` for each `new`, exactly one `delete[]` for each `new[]`. You have more `delete`s than `new`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont want this:

```
delete &len;
delete &isNegative;
```

deleting instance variables like this is undefined bahaviour so your program can stop

Comment: 3 HOURS OF DEBUGGING....FINALLY SOMEONE FIXED IT!!!! im so sorry I have a midterm tomorrow and I was near tears in frustration when my code didnt work properly. I am so upset I wasted so much time !! but I finally know - and I wont make this mistake again!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::unique_ptr` and other *classes* to manage memory- always. Dynamic arrays particularly are suited to `std::vector<T>`. Do not manually manage your memory- you will get ALL THE ERRORS.

Comment: I could have implemented this entire class as a vector and it would have saved me much frustration that is certain. Thanks for your help.